# Remap Winkey and Disable It's Shortcuts

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

The purpose is for gaming and I want to remap the Winkey to some other key so the Start Menu doesn't pop on when I hit it, and I want to disable Winkey shortcuts like Winkey+e (which opens explorer.exe) while I'm in a game.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class LWJGL
    LWin::p
    return
    LWin & e::e
    return
#IfWinActive
```

Remapping doesn't get picked up by the games, Lwin is treated as Lwin but the Start Menu is blocked which is half of what we were aiming for.

But, if I press and hold the `Winkey` then the `e` key it opens `explorer.exe` which is not intended, I wish the `p` key and `e` key to have been pressed at this step.

Is there any AHK expert out there that has accomplished this?

I tried blocking the shortcut like this:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class LWJGL
    LWin::p
    return
    Lwin & e::
    return
#IfWinActive
```

But it would only send the `p` key, it omits the `e` key.

I also tried using the `Send` command with `Up` command like this:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class LWJGL
    LWin::p
    return
    LWin & e::
        Send {LWin Up}
        Send {e Down}
    return
    e Up::Send {e Up}
    return
#IfWinActive
```

Everything's fixed except the `e` key does nothing on it's own (pressing it solely does nothing, it only works if LWin is pressed and then `e` is pressed). Please note that the first issue is also not resolved here which means the LWin key is not remapped to `p` in the game.

---

The particular game that I'm testing on these scripts is Minecraft, but I also tested this on CS:GO and the LWin key doesn't get remapped to `p`, it's still treated as Winkey. This is not the case on Notepad.exe or other non-game programs, `LWin::p` remaps `Winkey` to `p`.

Comment: Try also `~LWin Up:: return` and `~RWin Up:: return`. See also [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/216893/how-to-enable-or-disable-the-keyboard-windows-key).

Comment: @harrymc That will permanently disable the Winkey! Not what I was looking for, and the article edits the registry which means I will lose the functionality of Winkey outside games, an app like SharpKeys remaps Winkey completely through registry but I want to be able to use the Winkey outside of the games.

Comment: You can limit its effect via `#IfWinActive`, as you did above.

Comment: But the point is, I want to use the Winkey for in-game keybindings...

Comment: This is a very problematic key to use this way. Another solution might be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows key is a problematic key to remap in AutoHotkey. This is because it cannot actually prevent Windows from seeing that Windows key was pressed, so [it needs to send extra simulated keystrokes to prevent start menu from opening](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_MenuMaskKey.htm). Your best bet for reliability in gaming is the following:

First remap the key using SharpKeys to a key that doesn't exist on your keyboard, like F15. Then remap this key separately for the cases when you are in the game and when you are not:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class LWJGL
    F15::p
#IfWinActive

#IfWinNotActive ahk_class LWJGL
    F15::LWin
#IfWinNotActive
```

(You don't need return statements for remappings or when a hotkey needs to execute only a single line.)

Comment: You're so smart.. I never thought of this. Thanks a lot for helping :D

Comment: There's just one tiny problem that I realized after 4 days.. Winkey+L Does not lock the computer anymore! and I tried `Esc::DllCall("LockWorkStation")` which worked but remapping it with Winkey did not work for example: `Winkey & L::DllCall("LockWorkStation")` or other combinations of Winkey did not lock the computer!

Comment: There is no Winkey in AutoHotkey; you would write it as `LWin & l`, or preferably as `#l`. However, that may not work either, since, from AutoHotkey's point of view, you are pressing F15, so `F15 & l` is probably better. Try both of them (`#l` and `F15 & l`) both inside and outside the #Ifs and see which works for you. (Remapped keys may or may not trigger other hotkeys depending on whether they are _hook hotkeys_, [read more on here](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#remarks).)

Comment: Wow, That was an instant fix!! `F15 & L` works perfect!!! Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is remap the key itself, you don't need to remap the LWin key combos.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class LWJGL
    LWin::p
#IfWinActive
```

With `LWin & e::e` you're remapping it to "e". So any modifier keys are passed through. In this case, the Win key is passing through, so you get `Win + E`.

Note that thee `{blind}` allows all modifier keys to affect the keys you press, because if you remap a key to, say, "e", and you want it capitalized
You would hold the "Shift" and press your "remapped key".

Also note that a key remap uses `Send, {DownR}` method which has an effect similar to physically pressing the key for use with keyboard shortcuts.